# VBA to add date to each cell to the right of current selection?

Tags: vba, excel

I require some help with some Excel VBA I am working on, the current script checks a row for a date and if it is in the past it pastes a range to the next empty cell in row A. the range is currently 63 rows but may change.

What I need it to do is also add today's date to the cell to the right of each of these entries the script has just pasted.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim Adm As Worksheet
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim NextRow As Range

Set ws = Sheets("Booking Count")
Set Adm = Sheets("Admin")
Set rng1 = ws.Columns("B:B").Find("*", ws.[B1], xlValues, , xlByRows, xlPrevious)

If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then
If CDate(rng1) < Date Then
    Set NextRow = ws.Range("A" & ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count - 61)
    Adm.Range("AllStaff").Copy
    ws.Activate
    NextRow.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Set NextRow = Nothing
    Sheets("Home").Activate
    Else
    MsgBox "The date entered into the TextBox is equal to today or later."
End If
Else
End If
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: The `now()` function will give you today's date.

Comment: Thanks, I am away of that one. my issue is trying to get the date next to every cell that has been pasted from the Adm.Range which is about 63 cells. Using the 
     NextRow.Offset(0, 1).Value = Now()
works for the first cell but not the rest.

Comment: When I use `.Offset(0,1)` on a range, it puts the `now` value in each of the cells in the range.

Comment: I see what's going wrong. The NextRow is a single cell, there is no named range for the paste. I have just added a new named raged it its working. Thanks heaps!

Answer (score 0):

Needed to name the pasted range before offsetting and adding the date.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim Adm As Worksheet
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim NextRow As Range
Dim NextRow2 As Range

Set ws = Sheets("Booking Count")
Set Adm = Sheets("Admin")
Set rng1 = ws.Columns("B:B").Find("*", ws.[B1], xlValues, , xlByRows, xlPrevious)

If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then
If CDate(rng1) < Date Then
    Set NextRow = ws.Range("A" & ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count - 61)
    Adm.Range("AllStaff").Copy
    ws.Activate
    NextRow.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Transpose:=False
    Set NextRow2 = Selection
    Selection.Offset(0, 1).Value = Now()
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Set NextRow = Nothing
    Sheets("Home").Activate
    Else
    MsgBox "The date entered into the TextBox is equal to today or later."
End If
Else
End If
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not sure I follow *why* that's happened, but glad to have helped.